# Taylor series expansion of $f(x_n + f(x_n))$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, taylor-expansion

Currently I am stuck at trying to understand a proof that uses the fact that the Taylor series expansion of a continuous function $f$ at $f(x_n + f(x_n))$ is $f(x_n + f(x_n)) \approx f(x_n) + f'(x_n)f(x_n) + \frac{1}{2}f''(\eta)f(x_n)^2$, where $\eta$ in between $x_n$ and $x_n + f(x_n)$. Specifically my problem is that I don't know how to connect the used expression with the typical Taylor series expansion of a function $f$ at around a point $a$: $f(x; a) = f(a) + f'(a)(x - a) + \frac{1}{2}f''(a)(x - a)^2 + \dots + \frac{1}{n!}f^{(n)}(x - a)^n$.

Why is $\eta$ in between $x_n$ and $x_n + f(x_n)$? Why seemingly $(x - a) := f(x_n)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taylor series are arrived at from Taylor's theorem.  Its most common form states that if a function $f$ is $n$ times differentiable in the open interval between $a$ and $b$ and its $(n-1)$th derivative $f^{(n-1)}$ is continuous in the closed interval, then, a number $\eta$ exists strictly between $a$ and $b$ such that,
$$
f(b) = f(a) + (b-a)f'(a)+ \cdots + \frac{(b-a)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} f^{(n-1)}(a) + \frac{(b-a)^{n}}{n!} f^{(n)}(\eta).
$$
The theorem works for $b-a$ positive or negative.  Note that the first terms are the same as your Taylor expansion with $b=x$ but its essence is also to provide an explicit and exact expression for the remainder after summing the first $n$ terms.

It is derived using the "mean value theorem" applied to the function,
$$g(x) = F_n(x) - \left(\frac{b-x}{b-a}\right)^n F_n(a)$$
for $x$ between $a$ and $b$ and $$F_n(x) = f(b)-\left( f(x) + (b-x)f'(x) + \cdots + \frac{(b-x)^{n-1} }{(n-1)!} f^{(n-1)}(x)\right).$$
With this definition $g$ is continuous in the closed interval, differentiable in the open interval and $g(a)=g(b) = 0$.  It therefore follows $g'(\eta) = 0$ for some $\eta$ strictly between $a$ and $b$;  when you calculate $g'(\eta)$ you obtain Taylor's theorem.

Then in you question simply apply Taylor's theorem with $n=2$, $a = x_n$ and $b=x_n+f(x_n)$ assuming $f$ meets the necessary conditions.  By definition, $$b-a = x_n + f(x_n) - x_n = f(x_n)$$ and Taylor's theorem says some $\eta$ exists between $x_n$ and $x_n+f(x_n)$ which makes the approximate equality you quote actually an exact equation.

I hope that helps.